# Visual Studio 2015 not recognizing references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a solution with some projects. I am in project 23 and I added a reference to project 5, but Visual Studio does not recognize any class from project 5 nor the project 5. I tried using _05. Nothing works. Am I doing something wrong?[image]

Comment: That's strange behavoiur. And can you reference to any object from namespace "_05" without adding "using" directive?

Comment: Yes, I can but the using directive doesnt seem to work. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: Now I have noticed that only after I try to use the namespace Visual Studio accepts the using directive. Why do you think this happens? Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: Look at @Artem's answer - he is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes in 05 should be public.

```
public class Ejerkikio_05
{
....
```

Comment: You are right. It seems that if there are no public classes it won't let us use the using directive at all. Thanks!